# Does Drupal 7 have a better way of managing development changes than Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

So one hassle of Drupal 6 is that it's tough to move changes from a development server to a test or staging server to a production server.

Has this been made easier in Drupal 7? Is there some coding conventions module developers are suppose to follow now. So a developer can easily separate content and configuration and only move configuration between dev, test, and prod?

Is the [recommended advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652760/syncing-drupal-site-between-dev-staging-and-production) to still use the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no additional features in Drupal 7 that specifically address the deployment issues. Features will probably continue to be the best solution to that set of issues, for some time. However, some of the new features in Drupal 7 such as entities and fields in core may make it easier, when creating a module, to expose its configuration data to Features.